# Resolve Uri failed on bad bitmap Uri

Tags: android, bitmap, uri

I am new to Android development.

Please help me regarding the following issue. I'm  getting the error "system.out - resolveuri failed on bad bitmap uri" on Logcat when I tried to update the widget using the function,

```
 remoteViews.setImageViewUri(R.id.clockview, buildUpdate("CURRENTTIME", c));    
    awm.updateAppWidget(awID, remoteViews);
```

I am attaching my code:-

```
    public Uri buildUpdate(String time, Context context) {


        date = new Date();
        sec = (float) date.getSeconds();
        min = (float) date.getMinutes();
        hour = (float) date.getHours() + min / 60.0f;
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
        p.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        p.setStrokeWidth(2);
        canvas.drawLine(
                x,
                y,
                (float) (x + (r - 15)
                        * Math.cos(Math
                                .toRadians((hour / 12.0f * 360.0f) - 90f))),
                (float) (y + (r - 10)
                        * Math.sin(Math
                                .toRadians((hour / 12.0f * 360.0f) - 90f))), p);
...
...
 OutputStream outStream = null;
        File file = new File("data/clockbitmap.PNG");
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
     }
     catch(Exception e)
       {}
       uri = Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());

        Log.d("File","filename "+file);
        Log.d("here", "Does this exist? " + String.valueOf
                (file.exists()));
        Log.d("here",uri.getPath());
    return uri;
```

}

Please help me regarding this.!!!!! :(

Comment: btw, buildUpdate() is not a good method name....

Answer (score 0):

As you are reading a file from sd card the path can be given as " file:/// (absolute path.)"

I feel this will solve the URI parsing issue.

Comment: I used this code.
String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
  File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "clockbitmap.PNG");